# What is the need of having both System.map file and /proc/kallsyms?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I just want to know the difference between *`System.map`* file and *`/proc/kallsyms`*.
I am using Linux 3.16 generic kernel. I know that both are the kernel symbol table.. When I did a compare on this files, both are having the same content.
So what is the need of having both?

Comment: You can not be really sure that system.map will be available on your system. And even if its there you cant be sure if its of the booted kernel. So kallsyms is the symbols of running kernel.

Comment: So it means there is no need of System.map file.. Then why it is generated ?

Comment: What if your kernel never boots and get stuck. and you want to debug it?

Comment: Yaa . Then it  may be useful... Are there any other situations where System.map file is used?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`/proc/kallsyms` have symbols of dynamically loaded modules as well static code and `System.map` is symbol tables of only static code.

You can not be really sure if `System.map` will be available on your system.  When kernel and system.map mismatch you keep seeing `System.map does not match actual kernel` warning. So in that case`/proc/kallsyms` is the symbols of running kernel.

System.map isn't just useful for debugging kernel oopses. A few drivers need System.map to resolve symbols since they're linked against kernel headers instead of glibc). They won't work correctly without the System.map for the particular kernel currently running.

More info on http://dirac.org/linux/system.map/

Answer (score 4):

In short, if kaslr is not enabled,

```
system.map = $(nm vmlinux)
/proc/kallsysms = system.map + loaded modules's kallsyms
```