# Why does my /proc/kallsyms file not contain all the symbols in System.map?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, symbols, kbuild

I saw from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28936630/system-map-file-and-proc-kallsyms) that `/proc/kallsyms` should have the symbols of dynamically loaded modules as well as static code whereas `System.map` contains only the symbols of static code. However, when I `cat /proc/kallsyms` I seem to only have symbols in the text section of the kernel (`T` and `t` flags), save one or two symbols like

```
0000000000000000 D irq_stack_union
0000000000000000 D __per_cpu_start
```

On the other hand, in `System.map` I have symbols from many sections - essentially everything from `/proc/kallsyms` except loaded kernel module symbols.

To show the magnitude of this difference I used the `wc` command.

```
user@debian:~/$ cat /boot/System.map-3.2.0-4-amd64 | wc
  51256  153768 2117121
user@debian:~/$ cat /proc/kallsyms | wc
  29336   92637 1161409
```

What is the reason for this difference? Where are all of the data section related symbols in my `/proc/kallsyms` file?

Edit: As requested, here are the `kallsyms` configuration options.

```
user@debian:~$ cat /boot/config-3.2.0-4-amd64 | grep KALLSYMS
CONFIG_KALLSYMS=y
# CONFIG_KALLSYMS_ALL is not set
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System.map file and /proc/kallsyms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28936630/system-map-file-and-proc-kallsyms)

Comment: Thank you, but no it doesn't. That is the post I linked above. I get why and how `kallsyms` and `System.map` should be different due to that post, but my question reflects a different situation than that post.

Comment: Sorry about that.. My guess is that /proc/kallsyms is derived from the internal data structures used to print opps messages, so it never had a reason to store the address of symbols outside of the .text section. The kernel doesn't actually keep the non-text symbols in memory.

Comment: Does using `sudo cat` change anything? Also, what's the output of the `uname -r` command?

Comment: Hi @MarcoBonelli using `sudo` doesn't change anything. Output of `uname -r` is `3.2.0-4-amd64`.

Comment: @peachykeen can you also check the output of: `sudo cat /boot/config-3.2.0-4-amd64 | grep KALLSYMS`, those config options are relevant, add it to the post.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli : I added the output to my post above. Not having `CONFIG_KALLSYMS_ALL` set to `y` seems like it is my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have `CONFIG_KALLSYMS_ALL` set to `y`, therefore only text symbols are exported to `/proc/kallsyms`. Setting this to `y` and re-building the kernel (although not that simple to do) should solve the problem.

I don't know if this is because you have an old kernel or some distro that disables it in their build. You could also try upgrading to a newer kernel. In my Debian 9 Linux v4.9 it seems to be enabled.